# Split string by character in a loop

Tags: bash

I want to determine on macOS which version of .NET runtimes I have installed.
I'm using command `dotnet --list-runtimes` to print available versions.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.9 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.11 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.9 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.11 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Would love to create an array with above versions like `["6.0.9, "6.0.11"]` to be able to see if there's a version higher or equal than, for example, 6.0.11.

I have a code that looks like this:

```
if [[ -f "/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet" ]]
then
    IFS=' '
    declare sdks=$(dotnet --list-runtimes)
    for runtime in "${sdks}"
    do
        echo $runtime
        declare split=("")
        read -a split <<< $runtime
        echo ${split[1]}
    done
    IFS=''
else
    echo "ERROR: Unable do determine installet .NET SDK."
fi
```

Unfortunately `echo ${split[1]}` prints only once 6.0.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check:

```
$ array=( $(dotnet --list-runtimes | awk '{a[$2]=""}END{for (i in a) print i}') )
$ printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
6.0.9
6.0.11
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print unique versions then use:

```bash
dotnet --list-runtimes | awk '!seen[$2]++{print $2}'
```

If you want to create an array in bash 3.2 then use:

```bash
vers=()
while read -r v; do
   vers+=("$v")
done < <(dotnet --list-runtimes | awk '!seen[$2]++{print $2}')

# check array content
declare -p vers

declare -a vers=([0]="6.0.9" [1]="6.0.11")
```

**Breakdown:**

- `awk '!seen[$2]++{print $2}'`: prints unique version numbers from field #2
- `< <(...)` is process substitution
- `readarray` populates given array `vers` using output of process substitution

Comment: If you want to just get unique versions then `awk` solution is simplest without using so many commands. If you want to create a shell array in bash 3.2 then please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bash version:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a sdks
while read -r runtime; do
    set $runtime
    sdks+=("$2")
done < <(dotnet --list-runtimes)

echo "${sdks[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for your purposes?

```
dotnet --list-runtimes | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | sort | uniq | xargs
6.0.11 6.0.9
```

---

Update

As used in a loop:

```
> for version in $(dotnet --list-runtimes | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | sort | uniq | xargs); do echo $version; done
6.0.11
6.0.9
```

Comment: The returned value is not array which I can loop over, am I correct?

Comment: of course you could